# Dynamically create tests with cy.task

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, cypress

I'd like to generate identical tests with variable data in Cypress. The idea is that testers can create new folders in the `fixtures` folder, and these folders will automatically be picked up and used to generate new tests.

I've created this snippet in my `plugins/index.js`. When `cy.task('getAllDirectories', 'someURL')` is called it will give me a list of all sub-directories inside `someURL`.

```js
const { readdirSync, lstatSync } = require('fs');
const { join } = require('path');
const _ = require('lodash');

const isDirectory = source => lstatSync(source).isDirectory();

module.exports = (on, config) => {
  on('task', {
    getAllDirectories(source) {
      const fullSource = `${process.cwd()}/cypress/${source}`;

      return readdirSync(fullSource)
        .map(name => join(fullSource, name))
        .filter(isDirectory)
        .map(name => _.last(name.split('/')));
    },
  });
};
```

This seems to work just fine, I've managed to call it successfully inside `it()` and `before()` in Cypress. The problem however is that since these dynamically generated tests are the only ones in this file, this code inside my context doesn't run at all.

```js
let TESTS = [];

  before(() => {
    cy.task('getAllDirectories', '').then((output) => {
      TESTS = output;
      cy.log(TESTS);
    });
  });
```

Even when I add a dummy test like `it('dummy', () => {})`, the TESTS variable is set to the new name array, but it's too late to generate tests, when I try to iterate it below the before method.

```
TESTS.forEach((TEST) => {
    it(`Validates request: ${TEST}`, () => {
      ...
```

So I figured I need to call `cy.task` outside of a test or `before` hook, however putting it only inside `context()` says that `cy.task` must be ran inside a test.

Comment: If you only want to run certain spec files, you might be able to do it by globbing with a command line parameter e.g `--spec cypress/integration/my-tests/**/*.e2e.spec.js`

Comment: It's not about wanting to run specific spec files. I want to run a single spec file, using different sets of data. For the spec file to know what date to run with, it needs to read the file system and detect all directories in a specific folder, then create tests for each one (a test being a `it` block, not a new spec file)

Comment: The basic problem you have with this approach is that Cypress needs to see the content of the entire spec upon loading. You can't add `it()` blocks after the load - which you already know from what you tried.

Comment: The bit that's wrong in your thinking is the 'create tests' concept. You can pre-define tests in the spec file and conditionally or iteratively call them depending on the data fetched from a fixture.

Comment: If you post an example test, can look at refactoring needed.

Comment: I have almost same need. I need to create tests for each data file I have in data directory. It's total random, so I cannot create pre-defined tests in spec file as @RichardMatsen said. I know WebDriverIO has so nice support of doing this. At least cypress should have some mechanism to execute cy.task outside it() or other functions. For ugly solution, I need to have one it() and in that iterate over all data and have tests..

Comment: @Jaydeep - why not post your 'ugly' solution, might help GMchris. From your comment I think you misunderstand how data driven tests can work in Cypress. So, if you post an answer maybe can help you too.

Comment: @RichardMatsen- In my case actually data is not exactly data may be! I organize test data in separate file, and data in file is just props of component. So each file is kind of test case. I can show that in storybook. And in cypress I can get all those file names and make tests to take screenshot for vr-test. So for solution: `it('take screenshots', () => { /* const data = await cy.task('getData'); */ data.forEach((datum) => { cy.visit('http://localhost:9090?page=${datum}'); }) })`. So If I can do this iteration outside `it()`, it will be more nice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I had almost similar requirement like that as I said in comment. And I found that there is no straight way to do that in cypress.

So I did it in indirect way but still target can be achieved, may be not 100% nice solution.

I made script which gathers necessary info and export data as json in `cypress/fixtures`. I will write steps as psuedo-code:

```
Let say file named: load-test-data.ts

1. Search for all spec files in my project
2. Find directory having data in each spec file's directory
3. Build object of information which contains:
  {
     [specFilePath]: {
       componentName,
       data,
     }
  }
where 'data' is data for which I want to generate tests.
4. Generate JSON and save in cypress/fixtures/test-data.json
```

Then in my test utility (which generates tests)

```js
describe('Should test component', () => {

  const path = Cypress.spec.relative;
  const fixtureData = require('../../../cypress/fixtures/test-data.json');

  const info = fixtureData[path];

  info.data.forEach((datum) => {
    it(`Should pass test for ${datum}`, () => {
      cy.visit(`http://localhost:9001/?page=${datum}`); // this is not real, just for demo purpose!!

      // and do something more
    });
  });

});
```

And then when I wanna run cypress, I do:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Generate fixture which will contain test-data to generate tests
./node_modules/.bin/ts-node  load-test-data.ts

# Run cypress
./node_modules/.bin/cypress run
```

I hope this helps!